# getAttributes from principal (ticket) returns null - CAS

Tags: authentication, attributes, single-sign-on, cas

I'm developing a project using the CAS as an authentication server, which so far can make user authentication and have access to the ticket. However when I try to access attributes of the ticket by the "(Map) ticket.getAttributes ()" (using database with jdbc) CAS returns null. Below are the settings in the deployerConfigContext.xml file and the code block where I try to access the ticket attributes:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <util:map id="authenticationHandlersResolvers">
        <entry key-ref="proxyAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver" />
        
  <entry key-ref="SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="primaryPrincipalResolver" />
    </util:map>

 <!-- Required for proxy ticket mechanism -->
    <bean id="proxyPrincipalResolver"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.BasicPrincipalResolver" />
    
 <bean id="primaryPrincipalResolver"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver" >
        <property name="attributeRepository" ref="singleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao" />
    </bean>

 <bean id="iPersonAttributeDao" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.IPersonAttributeDao"/>
 
 <bean id="singleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao"
    class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="SELECT * FROM user WHERE {0}" />
    <property name="queryAttributeMapping">
        <map>
   <entry key="id" value="1" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="email" value="email" />
        </map>
    </property>
 </bean>
 
 
 <bean id="serviceRegistryDao" class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl">
 <property name="registeredServices">
   <list>
     <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl">
       <property name="id" value="0" />
       <property name="name" value="HTTP" />
       <property name="description" value="Only Allows HTTP Urls" />
       <property name="serviceId" value="http://**" />
       <property name="evaluationOrder" value="10000001" />
       <property name="allowedAttributes">
        <list>
          <value>email</value>
          
  </list>
  </property>
  </bean>
 </list>
  </property>
  </bean>

    <util:list id="authenticationMetadataPopulators">
        <ref bean="successfulHandlerMetaDataPopulator" />
        <ref bean="rememberMeAuthenticationMetaDataPopulator" />
    </util:list>

    

    <alias name="acceptUsersAuthenticationHandler" alias="primaryAuthenticationHandler" />
    <alias name="personDirectoryPrincipalResolver" alias="primaryPrincipalResolver" />

    <alias name="serviceThemeResolver" alias="themeResolver" />

    <alias name="jsonServiceRegistryDao" alias="serviceRegistryDao" />

    <alias name="defaultTicketRegistry" alias="ticketRegistry" />

    <alias name="ticketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy" alias="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" />
    <alias name="multiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy" alias="serviceTicketExpirationPolicy" />

    <alias name="anyAuthenticationPolicy" alias="authenticationPolicy" />
    <alias name="acceptAnyAuthenticationPolicyFactory" alias="authenticationPolicyFactory" />

    <bean id="auditTrailManager"
          class="org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager"
          p:entrySeparator="${cas.audit.singleline.separator:|}"
          p:useSingleLine="${cas.audit.singleline:false}"/>

    <alias name="neverThrottle" alias="authenticationThrottle" />

    <util:list id="monitorsList">
        <ref bean="memoryMonitor" />
        <ref bean="sessionMonitor" />
    </util:list>

    <alias name="defaultPrincipalFactory" alias="principalFactory" />
    <alias name="defaultAuthenticationTransactionManager" alias="authenticationTransactionManager" />
    <alias name="defaultPrincipalElectionStrategy" alias="principalElectionStrategy" />
    <alias name="tgcCipherExecutor" alias="defaultCookieCipherExecutor" />
 
 <bean id="dataSource"
   class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
   p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste"
   p:user="root"
   p:password="123456789"
   />
   
 <!-- Authentication method end-->
 <bean id="passwordEncoder"
      class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.DefaultPasswordEncoder"
      c:encodingAlgorithm="MD5"
      p:characterEncoding="UTF-8" />

 <bean id="SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler"
      class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:passwordEncoder-ref="passwordEncoder"
      p:tableUsers="user"
      p:fieldUser="email"
      p:fieldPassword="password" />
</beans>
```

code block:

```
AttributePrincipal ticket = (AttributePrincipal) req.getUserPrincipal();
Map attributes = ticket.getAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how it works. See https://github.com/UniconLabs/cas-sample-java-webapp as an example of how Java CAS client works:

https://github.com/UniconLabs/cas-sample-java-webapp/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.jsp

Comment: My problem is the access method "principal.getAttributes ()", it always returns null. I wanted to know what settings should I do to make the CAS seek these attributes in my database.

Comment: See https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/integration/Attribute-Release.html

Comment: Your CAS client must also be able to retrieve attributes by using the right v3 validator.

Comment: Sorry, what's v3 validator?

Comment: https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client#orgjasigcasclientvalidationcas30proxyreceivingticketvalidationfilter

Comment: In my main application as substitutes for Cas30ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter and try to deploy gives the following exception: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter.<init>(Lorg/jasig/cas/client/Protocol;)V
atorg.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas30ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter.<init>(Cas30ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter.java:36)

Comment: And java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: casServerUrlPrefix cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by following the Misagh Moayyed recommendations by changing the web.xml file filter "Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter" to "Cas30ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter" and some settings in the file "deployerConfigContext.xml":

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <util:map id="authenticationHandlersResolvers">
        <entry key-ref="proxyAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver" />
        
  <entry key-ref="SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver" />
    </util:map>
 
 <!-- Required for proxy ticket mechanism -->
    <bean id="proxyPrincipalResolver"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.BasicPrincipalResolver" />

    <util:list id="authenticationMetadataPopulators">
        <ref bean="successfulHandlerMetaDataPopulator" />
        <ref bean="rememberMeAuthenticationMetaDataPopulator" />
    </util:list>
 
 
 <!-- Attribute Repository -->
 <bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
  <constructor-arg index="1" value="SELECT * FROM user u WHERE {0}" />
  <property name="queryAttributeMapping">
     <map>
     <entry key="username" value="email" />
     </map>
  </property>
  <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
   <map>
    <entry key="email" value="username"/>
    <entry key="id" value="id"/>
    <entry key="password" value="password"/>
    <entry key="campoteste" value="campoteste"/>
   </map>
  </property>
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="serviceRegistryDao"
          class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl">
  <property name="registeredServices">
   <list>
    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
     <property name="id" value="0" />
     <property name="name" value="HTTP and IMAP" />
     <property name="description" value="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols" />
     <property name="serviceId" value="^(https?|imaps?)://.*" />
     <property name="evaluationOrder" value="10000001" />
    </bean>
   </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <alias name="acceptUsersAuthenticationHandler" alias="primaryAuthenticationHandler" />
    <alias name="personDirectoryPrincipalResolver" alias="primaryPrincipalResolver" />

    <alias name="serviceThemeResolver" alias="themeResolver" />

    <alias name="jsonServiceRegistryDao" alias="serviceRegistryDao" />

    <alias name="defaultTicketRegistry" alias="ticketRegistry" />

    <alias name="ticketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy" alias="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" />
    <alias name="multiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy" alias="serviceTicketExpirationPolicy" />

    <alias name="anyAuthenticationPolicy" alias="authenticationPolicy" />
    <alias name="acceptAnyAuthenticationPolicyFactory" alias="authenticationPolicyFactory" />

    <bean id="auditTrailManager"
          class="org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager"
          p:entrySeparator="${cas.audit.singleline.separator:|}"
          p:useSingleLine="${cas.audit.singleline:false}"/>

    <alias name="neverThrottle" alias="authenticationThrottle" />

    <util:list id="monitorsList">
        <ref bean="memoryMonitor" />
        <ref bean="sessionMonitor" />
    </util:list>

    <alias name="defaultPrincipalFactory" alias="principalFactory" />
    <alias name="defaultAuthenticationTransactionManager" alias="authenticationTransactionManager" />
    <alias name="defaultPrincipalElectionStrategy" alias="principalElectionStrategy" />
    <alias name="tgcCipherExecutor" alias="defaultCookieCipherExecutor" />
 
 <bean id="dataSource"
   class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
   p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cas"
   p:user="root"
   p:password="123456789"
   />
   
 <!-- Authentication method end-->
 <bean id="passwordEncoder"
      class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.DefaultPasswordEncoder"
      c:encodingAlgorithm="MD5"
      p:characterEncoding="UTF-8" />

 <bean id="SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler"
      class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:passwordEncoder-ref="passwordEncoder"
      p:tableUsers="user"
      p:fieldUser="email"
      p:fieldPassword="password" />
</beans>
```

"Cas.properties":

```
server.name=https://localhost:8444
server.prefix=${server.name}/cas

# security configuration based on IP address to access the /status and /statistics pages
# cas.securityContext.adminpages.ip=127\.0\.0\.1


##
# Unique CAS node name
# host.name is used to generate unique Service Ticket IDs and SAMLArtifacts.  This is usually set to the specific
# hostname of the machine running the CAS node, but it could be any label so long as it is unique in the cluster.
host.name=localhost

##
# JPA Service Registry Database Configuration
#
# svcreg.database.ddl.auto=create-drop
 svcreg.database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
# svcreg.database.hibernate.batchSize=10
 svcreg.database.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 svcreg.database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/cas
 svcreg.database.user=root
 svcreg.database.password=123456789
 svcreg.database.pool.minSize=6
 svcreg.database.pool.maxSize=18
 svcreg.database.pool.maxWait=10000
 svcreg.database.pool.maxIdleTime=120
 svcreg.database.pool.acquireIncrement=6
 svcreg.database.pool.idleConnectionTestPeriod=30
 svcreg.database.pool.connectionHealthQuery=select 1
 svcreg.database.pool.acquireRetryAttempts=5
 svcreg.database.pool.acquireRetryDelay=2000
##

database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
#database.ddl.auto=create
#database.hibernate.batchSize=10
 database.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/cas
 database.username=root
 database.password="123456789"
 database.driver.class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 database.pool.minSize=6
#database.user=root
 database.pool.maxSize=18
 database.pool.maxWait=10000
 database.pool.maxIdleTime=120
 database.pool.acquireIncrement=6
 database.pool.idleConnectionTestPeriod=30
 database.pool.connectionHealthQuery=select 1
 database.pool.acquireRetryAttempts=5
 database.pool.acquireRetryDelay=2000


cas.jdbc.authn.query.sql=select password from users where username=?

# CAS UI Theme Resolution
#
 cas.themeResolver.defaultThemeName=cas-theme-default


##
# CAS PersonDirectory Principal Resolution
#
# cas.principal.resolver.persondir.principal.attribute=cn
 cas.principal.resolver.persondir.return.null=false



# IPv4 version
cas.securityContext.status.allowedSubnet=127.0.0.1


cas.securityContext.serviceProperties.service = ${server.prefix}/services/j_acegi_cas_security_check
cas.securityContext.serviceProperties.adminRoles=ROLE_ADMINISTRATORS
cas.securityContext.casProcessingFilterEntryPoint.loginUrl=${server.prefix}/login
cas.securityContext.ticketValidator.casServerUrlPrefix=${server.prefix}
cas.viewResolver.basename=default_views


users.database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdata
users.database.username=root
users.database.password=""
users.database.driver.class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#users.database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
users.database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#users.database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

"HTTPSandIMAPS-10000001.json":

```html
{
  "@class" : "org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "^(https|imaps)://.*",
  "name" : "HTTPS and IMAPS",
  "id" : 10000001,
  "description" : "This service definition authorized all application urls that support HTTPS and IMAPS protocols.",
  "proxyPolicy" : {
    "@class" : "org.jasig.cas.services.RefuseRegisteredServiceProxyPolicy"
  },
  "evaluationOrder" : 10000,
  "usernameAttributeProvider" : {
    "@class" : "org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceUsernameProvider"
  },
  "logoutType" : "BACK_CHANNEL",
  "attributeReleasePolicy" : {
    "@class" : "org.jasig.cas.services.ReturnAllowedAttributeReleasePolicy",
 "allowedAttributes" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", ["email", "password", "id", "campoteste"] ],
    "principalAttributesRepository" : {
      "@class" : "org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.DefaultPrincipalAttributesRepository"
    },
    "authorizedToReleaseCredentialPassword" : false,
    "authorizedToReleaseProxyGrantingTicket" : false
  },
  "accessStrategy" : {
    "@class" : "org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy",
    "enabled" : true,
    "ssoEnabled" : true
  }
}
```

And then...

[Screenshot CAS Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNsxh.png)